# Navigation Bar Search Results

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I would like to add an search directly to my navigation bar (like Apple Maps).

[image]

So thats no the problem, I'll just create it as Searchbar:

```
    searchBar.placeholder = "Gebäude und Räume suchen"
    var rightNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightNavBarButton
```

But how should i solve to see the results? First ill tried to use an Adaptive Popover, and if the user enters at least 2 letters ill load the popover and show the results (so I am able to show an Popover on the iPad, and get a Fullscreen View on the iPhone) - but here i need to check on every keypress if the popover is still visible, AND if there is an adaptive popover I need to create the searchbar on the child-controller too.

So I am not sure how to solve such things like Apple Maps (iPhone and iPad Version) - can anyone give me some tipps how can I do that? Is that a Popover? A Custom View?

Edit:

The easiest way (and this is how its atm looks like) - I have a Button with an Search Icon, and if the user clicks on this SearchButton, ill load an "Search" Controller (with an Searchbar) - if the user clicks on one Result ill go "back" and show the result on the Map.

But I would prefer to make it like the Apple Maps App (with the difference between iPad and iPhone Version)

Comment: Have you implemented a searchDisplayController? 
you can set that controller to: displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar this would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks - but there is no properties for the UISearchController (the searchDisplayController is deprecated) - but hopefully there is another "easy" way to solve such things. I will check with the UISearchController (atm i am not using any Controller, because my results coming from a Webservice and i could only push them into an UITableView)

Comment: Well the apple maps app just shows one UIPopover that contains a tableViewController, can you elaborate more on the desired result that you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

I can see why this is confusing. The functionality you are looking for used to be provided by `UISearchDisplayController` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate`. But these methods are deprecated in iOS 8.

The way to go these days is to use a `UISearchController`. The docs explain it pretty well:

> You create a new search controller using the `initWithSearchResultsController`: method, passing in the view controller that manages the contents to be displayed. The `searchResultsUpdater` property contains the object that is responsible for updating the results. Often the object contained in the `searchResultsUpdater` property is the same as the view controller set during initialization. However, if you have created your own model object to filter and respond to queries, you can set it as the `searchResultsUpdater`.

The callback mechanism for presenting and dismissing the search results is provided by the `UISearchControllerDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

What apple do in iPad is using a UIPopover, i have previously done exactly the same thing for custom Maps app using the following delegates:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    //init a searchPopover with the view you want to show the results in and then call it 
    [self.searchPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[self.search bounds] inView:self.search permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    [self.searchPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    //update the tableview that is in the searchPopover
    //searchView is the view inside the popOver, filterResults is a custom method with an NSPredicate inside. 
    [self.searchView filterResultsUsingString:searchText];
}
```

In the view controller that will display the result, you implement delegation, so that when the user presses the desired button or row in that view, the parentview is notidifed and the popover is dismissed, you zoom on the annotation you want.

```
-(void)didSelectResult:(id)annotation
{   
    //so when you select the result, and call this delegate method:
    self.annotationToSelect = annotation;
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.search.text = @"";
    [self.searchPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code - i will try that out!